# How to call TextToSpeech activity from another activity?

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I have an activity (`MainActivity`) that implements `TextToSpeech` and works perfectly. When a button's `onClick` is called, it speaks whatever is typed in `EditText`.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener{

    private TextToSpeech engine;
    private EditText text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);
        engine = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

        Intent i=getIntent();
        Bundle b=i.getExtras();
        word=b.getString("word");
        speakText2(word);
    }

    // speakText is called by onClick button
    public void speakText(View v) {
        String textContents = text.getText().toString();
        engine.speak(textContents, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
    }

    public void speakText2(String textContents) {
        engine.speak(textContents, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int i) {
        if (i == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            //Setting speech Language
            engine.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
            engine.setPitch(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I want to call `MainActivity` from another activity and pass a string to speak up.
I tried:

```
MainActivity mainactivity = new MainActivity();
String word;
word = "speak";
mainactivity.speakText2(word); // Error
```

But, getting error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.speak(java.lang.CharSequence, int, android.os.Bundle, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at MainActivity.speakText2(TTSEngine.java:53)
```

I tried using intent from another activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("word", word);
startActivity(intent);
```

But, getting error:

```
I/TextToSpeech: Sucessfully bound to com.google.android.tts
W/TextToSpeech: speak failed: not bound to TTS engine
W/TextToSpeech: speak failed: not bound to TTS engine
W/TextToSpeech: speak failed: not bound to TTS engine
I/TextToSpeech: Connected to ComponentInfo{com.google.android.tts/com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService}
I/TextToSpeech: Set up connection to ComponentInfo{com.google.android.tts/com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService}
```

I tried to implement `TextToSpeech` in the activity I want to use it in. But, it does not work for the first time I call speakText2 and give error:

```
W/TextToSpeech: speak failed: not bound to TTS engine
I/TextToSpeech: Connected to ComponentInfo{com.google.android.tts/com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService}
I/TextToSpeech: Set up connection to ComponentInfo{com.google.android.tts/com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService}
```

For rest of the time it work perfectly. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I think you need to do some research about services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only let the engine speak, after onInit is done, so do following in onInit():

if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
     speakText2(word);

}

Comment: I tried using intent, but getting another error. I have updated my question. Also there is no XML file for MainActivity. I just want app to speak up the word and remain in same activity. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @Beginner Just do all the logic in one Activity or transform your MainActivity into a Service . I suggest using one Activity for everything if you need a quick fix but for a long run you should study Service

Comment: I did that, but it does not work for the 1st time. I have updated the question. How to fix it?

Comment: @Beginner looked more into the error , you nees to do onInit first and then call speak()

Comment: @Beginner the title of you question a bit miseading

Comment: I added `tts.speak(" ", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);`, but it was giving same error. But, adding `speakText2(word);` instead words!!.

Comment: @Beginner great! It was a pattern)) if I helped you solve your problem please accept the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an `Intent` to start an `Activity`. See https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

When you create your `Activity` instance manually the `onCreate` method is not called (and any other lifecycle methods) - that’s why you’re getting an NPE accessing your `engine` property - it wasn’t initialized.

Comment: But, there is no XML file for MainActivity. I just want app to speak up the word and remain in same activity. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I tried using intent, but getting another error. I have updated my question.

Comment: @Beginner See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129712/speak-failed-not-bound-to-tts-engine And maybe you can do this without the MainActivity - just a separate class to work with the engine?