# TTS stops to talk after some minute of working

Tags: android, text-to-speech

My app uses TTS.
Everything is ok with ALL the devices I tried.
Only with Meizu 6 Pro Plus after some minutes, the TTS stops to work.
I don't understand why. It comes back to work if somewhere in the code I setup TTS again (the same code is in onCreate):

```
myTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
```

for the init

```
 public void onInit(int initStatus) {
                //check for successful instantiation
                if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) myTTS.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());
                else if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.ERROR) Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.errorspeech), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

and for the speak

```
public static void speakWords(String speech) {
myTTS.speak(speech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
```

I get this message in the log:
speak failed: not bound to TTS engine
Someone knows what can be a reason of this strange behaviour? Thanks.

Comment: are you getting any message in logcat>?

Comment: speak failed: not bound to TTS engine. I setup myTTS in onCreate().

Comment: Check whether your input size is under the limit.  
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#getMaxSpeechInputLength()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Speak Failed Not Bound to TTS Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129712/speak-failed-not-bound-to-tts-engine)

Comment: The string is very short and the TTS at the begin, it works.

Comment: Although the cause of this problem is most likely the specific device, it still goes hand-in-hand with your code, and there is probably some way of changing your code in order to solve the problem... so you should provide enough code for people to reproduce the problem so people aren't just guessing.

Comment: Yes I think it is a problem with Meizu.

Answer (score 1):

You could only call speak() after onInit() was called, try like this:

```
   public void onInit(int initStatus) {
        //check for successful instantiation
        if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
             myTTS.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());
             myTTS.speak(speech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        } 
        else if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.ERROR) Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.errorspeech), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
```

Comment: I need to call myTTS.speak from others activity, everytime I need.